# Watson assistant context variable type

Tags: watson-assistant

Does anyone know how to get the type of context variable in Watson Assistant?

Are there types like int, Array, String, Object for context variable inside Watson Assistant in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Within the Watson Assistant context you will only find a regular json. Its data is strings, arrays, objects, integers, dates or booleans. But you  always will have to serialize and deserialize the context to be able to work with it using any programming code.

For you to know the data type you have to parse the json to an object (JSON.parse in Javascript) and then you can obtain the data type.

here you can find more information https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-api-client-get-context&locale=en&programming_language=javascript

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Of course the external system(with a high level programming language) can pass the type to Watson Assistant via another context variable, but I want to get the type inside Watson Assistant natively.

Comment: Because I need to branch the conversation base on context var type.

Answer (score 0):

Watson Assistant uses Autoboxing to process a context variable.

So `”123”` and `123` can be a number or a string depending on how it is referenced.

The safest approach is to treat everything as a fixed type depending on the variable name. But if user interaction is involved there is a chance what they type can break that.

Maybe expand on the “why” for this. If it is to generate business rules or API output, it’s a better pattern to have the application layer handle this.